# How to interpret a list parameter as an actual list, not a symbol?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, evaluation

I have a situation like this in my code:

```
(defparameter names (list "Alice" "John" "Jack"))
(defparameter pair '(:smt names))

(defun process (a-list) (first a-list))
```

Now `(process names)` is working fine but `(process (second pair))` returns an error (Cannot take CAR of NAMES). When I debug, I noticed that for the latter call the parameter is regarded as a symbol by `type-of`, not a values list (`listp` returns `nil`). How can I overcome this or what am I doing wrong? Isn't `(second pair)` the same thing as `names`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to check whether `(second pair)` is the same as `names` in your REPL.

```
CL-USER> (second pair)
NAMES
CL-USER> names
("Alice" "John" "Jack")
CL-USER> 'names
NAMES
CL-USER> (second (list ':smt names))
("Alice" "John" "Jack")
CL-USER> (second (list ':smt 'names))
NAMES
```

You can see that it's the same as `'names`; `pair` is a list of two symbols.

It's possible that you want to use `quasiquote` and evaluate `names` instead of quoting it:

```
CL-USER> (second `(:smt ,names))
("Alice" "John" "Jack")
```

Comment: Thanks. This works of course. I didn't think the outer quote to affect the conversion of symbol `names`to its actual values. Still trying to get used to LISP I guess.